# Proof of one of the operations on Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

This is a known operation on Random Variables (r.vs.):

If $(X_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ is a sequence of r.vs., then $\inf X_n$, $\liminf X_n$, as
well as $\sup X_n$ and $\limsup X_n$ are also r.vs.

Proof given in class :

Notice first that 
$\{\inf X_n \ge c\} = \bigcap_n \{X_n \ge c\} \in \mathcal F$. Hence, $\inf X_n$ is an r.v.

Let $L_n(\omega) := \inf \{X_r(\omega) : r \ge n\}$.

By the previous argument, $L_n$ is an r.v.

However, $L(\omega) := \liminf X_n(\omega) = \sup L_n(\omega)$.

Thus, $\{L \le c\} = \{\sup L_n \le c\} = \bigcap_n \{L_n \le c\} \in \mathcal F$, and $L$ is an r.v.

Now I dont understand how $\{\inf X_n \ge c\} = \bigcap_n \{X_n \ge c\}$ and later on $\{\sup L_n \le c\} = \bigcap_n \{L_n \le c\}$. As a result I do not understand the proof at all. Could someone please explain the proof? [I've attached the screenshot of the proof also just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE51u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show $\{\inf X_n \ge c\} = \bigcap_n \{X_n \ge c\}$, note the following statements are equivalent for any $\omega$ in the sample space:

- $\omega \in \{\inf X_n \ge c\}$
- $\inf X_n(\omega) \ge c$
- $c$ is a lower bound for $\{X_n(\omega) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (because $\inf X_n(\omega)$ is the *greatest* such lower bound)
- $X_n(\omega) \ge c$ for all $n$
- $\omega \in \{X_n \ge c\}$ for all $n$
- $\omega \in \bigcap_n \{X_n \ge c\}$.

The case $\{\sup L_n \le c\} = \bigcap_n \{L_n \le c\}$ is very similar.

Comment: Again, that 6th bullet, how do you understand it in this context? I'm not able to digest it at all. I'm not saying it is wrong, I'm saying I'm not able to grasp what it means.

Comment: The intersection $\bigcap_n A_n$ of some sets $A_n$ is the set of things that are elements of *every* $A_n$. That is, $\omega \in \bigcap_n A_n$ if and only if $\omega \in A_n$ for all $n$, by definition. The last step is just applying this definition.